# Same number is generated in RNG in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, winforms, random, visual-studio-2019

I am attempting to make a random number generator in VB 16 in Visual Studio, but every time I run this I keep getting 71, I've tried making it public, sharing it and several other things, but it won't work. I am trying to make a program that has the user guess a randomly generated number, and continue guessing until they get it, but for some reason the exact same number is chosen each time. It won't work properly specifically in window app forms. How do I get a random number each time?

```
Public Shared Randomize()
Dim value As Integer = CInt(Int((100 * Rnd()) + 1))

Public Sub EnterBtn_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles EnterBtn.Click
    Dim entervalue As String = EnterTxt.Text
    Dim chances As Integer
    Select Case entervalue
        Case > value
            ResTxt.Text = "Too big"
            chances += 1
        Case < value
            ResTxt.Text = "Too small"
            chances += 1
        Case = value
            ResTxt.Text = "Well done, you got it in " & chances & " tries"
    End Select
End Sub
```

Comment: Code samples should be complete and correct.

Comment: when exactly should a new random number be generated?

Comment: When the program first starts up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were close!  Here's a working example modifying your original logic:

```
   Private random As Random = New Random()
   Private value As Integer
   Private chances As Integer

   Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
      value = random.Next(1, 100)
      chances = 0
   End Sub

   Private Sub EnterBtn_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles EnterBtn.Click
      Select Case EnterTxt.Text
         Case > value
            chances += 1
            ResTxt.Text = "Too big"
         Case < value
            chances += 1
            ResTxt.Text = "Too small"
         Case = value
            chances += 1
            ResTxt.Text = "Well done, you got it in " & chances & " tries"

            'and reset for next attempt
            value = random.Next(1, 100)
            chances = 0
      End Select
   End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's some skeleton code for you:

```
Dim rnd As New Random()
For i as Integer = 0 to 10
  Console.WriteLine("{0,15:N0}", rnd.Next())
Next
```

Notice the `rnd.Next()` thing. Hope it helps.

Comment: You should create the random outside of the loop and not make a new random on each iteration

Comment: Indeed, I added the loop as an afterthough and well... I'm going to edit it right away. Thanks for letting me know.

Answer (score 0):

Since your code is not correct it is hard to pinpoint the problem.  It is also not clear what the code is supposed to do.

Try this

```
Private Shared PRNG As New Random ' add this 

value = PRNG.Next(1, 101)'this will set value to a random number between 1 and 100 inclusive
```

Comment: When the program is run it will bring up a window with a text box and button, and you have to try and guess the number, if too high, it will display so, if too low, it will display so, when the player gets the right number, it will tell them so and also the amount of attempts